# 404 for children in hierarchical custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, query, 404-error

I've tried all the solutions I can find on this and I'm still stuck. [This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77513/getting-hierarchical-custom-post-type-permalinks-to-work-just-like-pages?rq=1) has a good thorough approach to debugging, but it hasn't helped.

Part of the issue may be because I'm trying to get [the Flatpack theme](http://www.obox-design.com/theme.cfm/theme/flatpack) to change its behaviour. We're locked into this theme now. I'm doing this to make the portfolio and services CPTs hierarchical:

```
add_action( 'init', 'lf_modify_post_types', 999999 );
function lf_modify_post_types() {

if ( post_type_exists( 'portfolio' ) ) {

    $args = get_post_type_object( 'portfolio' );
    $args->rewrite['slug'] = 'portfolio';
    $args->rewrite['with_front'] = false;
    $args->hierarchical = true;
    $args->supports[] = 'page-attributes';
            $args->query_var = true;
    register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );

}

if ( post_type_exists( 'services' ) ) {

    $args = get_post_type_object( 'services' );
    $args->rewrite['slug'] = 'services';
    $args->rewrite['with_front'] = false;
    $args->hierarchical = true;
    $args->supports[] = 'page-attributes';
            $args->query_var = true;
    register_post_type( 'services', $args );

}

}
```

As far as I can see, this works to make sure all the relevant CPT settings are right (including setting `query_var` to true, which seems to be a common "solution" to this issue). A dump of the portfolio CPT object at the end of the above gives this:

```
stdClass Object (
[labels] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Portfolio
        [singular_name] => Portfolio
        [add_new] => Add Portfolio Item
        [add_new_item] => Add New Portfolio Item
        [edit_item] => Edit 
        [new_item] => New Portfolio Item
        [view_item] => View Portfolio Item
        [search_items] => Search Portfolio Items
        [not_found] => No portfolio items found
        [not_found_in_trash] => No portfolio items found in Trash
        [parent_item_colon] => 
        [all_items] => Portfolio
        [menu_name] => Portfolio
        [slug] => portfolio
        [name_admin_bar] => Portfolio
    )

[description] => 
[public] => 1
[hierarchical] => 1
[exclude_from_search] => 
[publicly_queryable] => 1
[show_ui] => 1
[show_in_menu] => 1
[show_in_nav_menus] => 1
[show_in_admin_bar] => 1
[menu_position] => 
[menu_icon] => http://languagefutures.localhost/wp-content/themes/language-futures/ocmx/images/icons/portfolio-icon.png
[capability_type] => post
[map_meta_cap] => 1
[register_meta_box_cb] => 
[taxonomies] => Array
    (
    )

[has_archive] => 
[rewrite] => Array
    (
        [slug] => portfolio
        [with_front] => 
        [pages] => 1
        [feeds] => 
        [ep_mask] => 1
    )

[query_var] => portfolio
[can_export] => 1
[delete_with_user] => 
[_builtin] => 
[_edit_link] => post.php?post=%d
[name] => portfolio
[cap] => stdClass Object
    (
        [edit_post] => edit_post
        [read_post] => read_post
        [delete_post] => delete_post
        [edit_posts] => edit_posts
        [edit_others_posts] => edit_others_posts
        [publish_posts] => publish_posts
        [read_private_posts] => read_private_posts
        [read] => read
        [delete_posts] => delete_posts
        [delete_private_posts] => delete_private_posts
        [delete_published_posts] => delete_published_posts
        [delete_others_posts] => delete_others_posts
        [edit_private_posts] => edit_private_posts
        [edit_published_posts] => edit_published_posts
        [create_posts] => edit_posts
    )

[label] => Portfolio
)
```

Flushed rules, and still:

http://languagefutures.localhost/portfolio/project-and-themes/ (works OK)
http://languagefutures.localhost/portfolio/project-and-themes/who-do-you-think-you-are/ (404)

I've used the Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin on the latter URL, and it shows:

```
portfolio/(.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$    index.php?portfolio=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]    portfolio
(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$            index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2] page
```

AFAIK all this is as it should be. Using the Query Monitor plugin, these are the queries being run that seem to be relevant:

```
SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent, post_type
FROM k3bex_posts
WHERE post_name IN ('project-and-themes','who-do-you-think-you-are')
AND (post_type = 'portfolio'
OR post_type = 'attachment')

Caller:
get_page_by_path()-
WP_Query->get_posts()
WP_Query->query()
WP->query_posts()
WP->main()
wp()

Returns: 2

SELECT k3bex_posts.*
FROM k3bex_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (k3bex_posts.ID = '1493')
AND k3bex_posts.post_parent = 0 
AND k3bex_posts.post_type = 'portfolio' 
ORDER BY k3bex_posts.post_date DESC

Caller:
WP_Query->get_posts()-
WP_Query->query()
WP->query_posts()
WP->main()
wp()

Returns: 0

SELECT ID
FROM k3bex_posts
WHERE post_name LIKE 'who-do-you-think-you-are%'
AND post_type = 'portfolio'
AND post_status = 'publish'

Caller:
redirect_guess_404_permalink()-
redirect_canonical()
do_action('template_redirect')

Returns: 1
```

The obvious stand-out is the second one. 1493 is indeed the right ID for the child page. Why is the query specifying post_parent = 0? I'm continuing to look into it but if anyone has experienced anything like this and survived, tips would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be interference from another Flatpack hack I had in place to stop it displaying child CPTs when outputting its widgets.

For reference, the damage was being done by a `pre_get_posts` hook. Worth checking this if you're similarly stuck.