# Display Child Pages of Custom Post Type Parent Page

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, child-pages, children

I am attempting to display the child pages of a custom `post_type` page. I found a shortcode that works great for standard WordPress "pages" `post_type`, but doesn't work on custom post types.

Here is the shortcode code I placed in my overrides functions file:

```
add_shortcode( 'my_childpages', 'my_list_child_pages' );  

function my_list_child_pages() { 
global $post;
if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
else
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
if ( $childpages ) {
    $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}
return $string; 
}
```

If I place the `[my_childpages]` shortcode on a "page" `post_type` with children it successfully displays in linked list all sub-pages. But if I add to a custom `post_type` (e.g., 'essays'), it doesn't.

I saw elsewhere that perhaps the code doesn't acknowledge the custom `$post_type`, and requires an added argument, but I'm not sure how to edit the above code to satisfy. I've tried several edits, but fail.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `page` itself is a custom post type, you can notice this when you open the edit page screen. Your URL will be like this:

```
www.example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page
```

This means you are on a `page` post type.

Now about your code, the first condition of your conditional determines if you are on a `page` post type or not. In the `else` section, you can also set the `post_type` as an argument:

```
$childpages = wp_list_pages( 'post_type=essay&sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
```

However, you have to have the hierarchical set to true while registering your custom taxonomy:

```
'hierarchical'=> true,
```

Take a look at [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77513/94498), which has some valuable information about this. The related page from the [code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) can also be useful.

Comment: Works beautifully! 

2 follow-up questions: 
(1) is there a way to list multiple post types as arg? e.g., could I add additional as comma separated list, or perhaps by adding multiple 'post_type=cpt1&post_type=cpt2&post_type=cpt3...'
(2) so basically, these are arguments with '&' instead of ',' as syntax?

Comment: 1) The arguments themselves can be either array or string. However, the `post_type` argument accepts only a string, which means it can only take a single value. Besides, have you thought about how will it be rendered if you use multiple post types? 2) If you use the string method, then yes you should use `&`. But if you pass an array, you should use `,` instead.